# Convertir formato de fecha en Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, google-chrome

estoy trabajando en una extensión de uso personal para google chrome y quisiera saber si es posible convertir una fecha en el siguiente formato de texto:

> 3 de octubre de 2020

... al formato:

> 03/10/2020

La fecha la obtengo desde el navegador en el formato inicial pero no logro encontrar información sobre este formato y supongo que se usa mayormente en medios en español.

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: ¿Agregarías por favor qué has intentado?

Comment: Ese formato depende del lenguaje, no hay ninguna funcion que te permita lo que indicas porque depende del lenguaje, asi que habria que crearla. y eso seria tedioso, seria mas facil usar un framework que ya tenga incluido esa funcionalidad.

Comment: es decir, puede ser "3 de octubre de 2020" como tambien puede ser de entrada "october 3 2020".

Comment: Lo siento, en realidad no sé por dónde empezar, supongo que si pudiera saber qué nombre se le da a este tipo de formato (inicial) podría trabajar en una solución.

Comment: busca bibliotecas como moment.js o luxon.js esas 2 te facilitarán el trabajo

Comment: @BetaM nunca he trabajado con bibliotecas pero es un comienzo, gracias por la información.

Comment: @Hellzing todos los comentarios que te están haciendo es porque en realidad JavaScript es una verdadera cagada para parsear strings que contienen fechas... Son básicamente 2 opciones: analizar el string manualmente, o usar una librería externa que te lo solucione... por eso de alguna forma es que tenés que definirte por una, intentarlo, y si se te complica, ahí vemos en dónde

Comment: @Pollo para ese caso en especifico si, pero el objeto Date enrealidad si tiene metodos que son bastante buenos, por ejemplo toLocalDateString etc, pero pues el usuario es necesita lo inverso del metodo toLocaleDateString...

Comment: @Riven y más flexible aún `Intl.DateTimeFormat().format(date)`... pero por eso dije "parsear strings" ;-)

Comment: @Hellzing tienes alguna forma de que los datos no te lleguen de la forma en la que indicas si no que te lleguen de manera numerica en millisegundos?, es decir, por ejemplo `8810249102` o algo parecido?, es que si logras que esa informacion te llegue en milisegundos posiblemente no necesites de ninguna libreria para poder hacer lo que necesitas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo comentado, no soy partidario de los `switch` ni los `if else` tan extensos

```js
const formatDate = ( date ) => {

  // Con una expesión regular quitamos "de" y dejamos minus todo
  const clearDate = date.replace( / de/g, '' ).toLowerCase();

  //Partimos la fecha
  const parts     = clearDate.split(' ');
  return buildDate( parts );
};

// Creamos una función para agregar los ceros
const addZero = ( n ) => Number( n ) >= 10 ? String( n ) : `0${n}`;

//Creamos el formato de la fecha
const buildDate = ( p ) => {
    // Creamos un mapa con los meses
  const months    = ['',
    'enero', 'febrero', 'marzo',
    'abril', 'mayo', 'junio',
    'julio', 'agosto', 'septiembre',
    'octubre', 'noviembre', 'diciembre'
  ];
  // Separamos los datos y buscamos el mes en los meses
  const year  = p[2];
  const month = addZero( months.indexOf( p[1] ) ) || '??';
  const day   = addZero( p[0] );
  return `${ day }/${ month }/${ year }`;
}

const date      = '3 de octubre de 2020';
const formatted = formatDate( date );

console.log( formatted );
```

Comment: muchas gracias por el aporte, en el momento no puedo hacer un test como es debido, tan pronto lo haga te comentaré como me ha ido. Los comentarios vienen muy bien para aquellos como yo con poca experiencia en programación web.

Comment: En efecto, funciona muy bien, muchas gracias por el aporte Alberto.

Answer (score 3):

Gracias a todos por las respuestas, en realidad no entendí cómo usar las librerias que me sugiere BetaM. Luxon parece ser muy apropiada para estos casos, trabajo con vsCode y estoy muy novato para entender muchas cosas, sin embargo con ayuda de algunas respuestas que encontré en los foros en Inglés pude escribir el siguiente codigo que me sirve para el caso en cuestión ya que solo necesito la fecha como string. Sin embargo si alguien quiere sugerir como convertir el string final a formato fecha podría ser de utilidad para alguien más.

Dejo mi "solución" por si alguien puede sugerir alguna manera de optimizarla ya que supongo que puede estar sujeta a posibles fallos.

```
    // Dividir Fecha
    var init_dte = "3 de octubre de 2020";
    var day = init_dte.split(" de")[0];
    var month = init_dte.split(" de ")[1];
    var year = init_dte.split(" de ")[2];

    // Agregar prefijo "0"
    if (day === "1") {
        day = "01";
    }
    if (day === "2") {
        day = "02";
    }
    if (day === "3") {
        day = "03";
    }
    if (day === "4") {
        day = "04";
    }
    if (day === "5") {
        day = "05";
    }
    if (day === "6") {
        day = "06";
    }
    if (day === "7") {
        day = "07";
    }
    if (day === "8") {
        day = "08";
    }
    if (day === "9") {
        day = "09";
    }

    // Convertir meses a formato numérico
    if (month === "enero") {
        month = "01";
    }
    if (month === "febrero") {
        month = "02";
    }
    if (month === "marzo") {
        month = "03";
    }
    if (month === "abril") {
        month = "04";
    }
    if (month === "mayo") {
        month = "05";
    }
    if (month === "junio") {
        month = "06";
    }
    if (month === "julio") {
        month = "07";
    }
    if (month === "agosto") {
        month = "08";
    }
    if (month === "septiembre") {
        month = "09";
    }
    if (month === "octubre") {
        month = "10";
    }
    if (month === "noviembre") {
        month = "11";
    }
    if (month === "diciembre") {
        month = "12";
    }

    // Construir Fecha
    var d = (day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
    console.log("Fecha: " + d);
```

Edit:
Sugerencia de Ricardo Sánchez, utilizar la instrucción switch:

```
    switch(month) {
      case "enero":
        text = "01";
        break;
      case "febrero":
        text = "02";
        break;
      case "marzo":
        text = "03";
        break;
        // así con los demás meses...
      default:
        text = "mes no existe"; // Sentencia a ejecutar si el valor no coincide con los enumerados.
    }
```

Comment: Excelente que tu mismo hagas una propuesta de solución + 1

Comment: Concuerdo contigo beta, excelente Hellzing.

Comment: @Hellzing ahora podrias mejorar tu codigo con un [switch](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

Comment: Gracias a todos por la ayuda! @Ricardo edito la respuesta con tu sugerencia para el caso de los meses.